# Reaching the ocean's end (EDIT: and the Earth's core)

Tags: society, geography

Today is it. Humanity has been waiting for this day ever since we started studying the ocean and its wonders. The waiting game is over; speculation will end.

After many attempts, nations have united to build this and succeeded: the first vehicle able to support massive pressure. According to the scientists calculations, enough to support a water column with the Earth radius size. This means that, if the way is free, "*Myth Breaker I*" will be able to reach the center of the Earth through the ocean.

The *"Myth Breaker I"* is equipped with cameras covering all angles; however, it is a small vehicle with a low transportation capacity.
Suppose the day has arrived: this futuristic vehicle WILL DIVE the ocean and seek its wonders. What would the *"Myth Breaker I"* find? What would be collected and recorded? And most important, how would it change humanity? Would it find hidden dinosaurs? Lost civilizations?

**Assume the following:**

- Although the vehicle can support massive pressure, there is no equipment for humans; this means the human crew can NOT leave the "Myth Breaker I";
- The resources used to make it are very very expensive. Therefore, only 2 vehicles have been made and there is no prediction that there will be another one;
- The storage capacity is extremely low and can only carry one or two samples of anything up to the size of 10 year old kid (approx.). It can however, get back to the ocean.

EDIT: Thank you all for the interesting answers, had no idea of the concepts presented there. Thank you so much. I have not read all answers, I only did a quick search through them; I will read them all in full as soon as possible, but honestly, I don't see the answer I wanted, maybe I wasn't clear enough; my biggest question was **what if we could reach the Earth's core through sea and explore every single inch of the sea and the Earth's core? We would certainly find new species, but what about lost continents? Civilizations? etc**.

Comment: And most important, how would it change humanity? this is your main question or you want to know what they will find ?

Comment: This question seems to be off-topic, or perhaps just asking too much.  Are you asking what would realistically be found, or what could be done in fantasy?  The question appears to imply that fantastical discoveries are allowed, but if so the question is too broad, It leaves the idea creation up to the answer.  Could you try to clarify rather you want realistic or fantastical answers, and generally narrow the focus of this question down?

Comment: @Jataki I assume you want to go to the center of the Earth via a safe passage in the ocean, probably you mean the Mariana Trench. I must say "Myth Breaker I" assuming it reached 11000m depth and did whatever James Cameron had done in 2012 you are still no where near the Earth's core. Having that said do me a tiny weeny favor please bring back any artifacts for me when you spot Atlantis we can split 50/50, thanks a lot.

Comment: I have bad news for you:  that scene in Star Wars 1 where they go through the planet core? It is not possible! (At least on Earth?)

Comment: @Vincent both!
dsollen any perspective is welcome! =D
user6760 this question assumes we did reached the Earth's core. LOL I will budd xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have already reached the bottom of the ocean, as already pointed out by spacemonkey.  There are still huge parts of the ocean unexplored, but I don't anticipate anything that will change humanity.

No human made artifacts will be found in the *DEEP* ocean.  There are no doubt plenty of ship wrecks we haven't discovered in other parts of the ocean, but the deepest depths of the ocean has such great pressure that nearly any man mad object will be destroyed in it.  In any case we have found plenty of ship wrecks in the past, while interesting it's doubtful anything will be discovered in a new one that will have any significant impact on humanity.

We could discover new fish and other aquatic animals, which is the most interesting thing left to find in the seas.  A very large percentage of earth's creatures live in the ocean, and many are not yet known to us. There are always opportunities to learn from new lifeforms we discover, but I doubt anything we learn will revolutionize humanity.  We may get discover some interesting facts of evolution by seeing how it works in such a resource deprived and high-pressure (literally!) enviroment, but that is not going to change the world.  We could possible discover creatures with novel evolutionary tricks, such as unique ways of generating light or 'seeing' in parts of the ocean where light rarely exists, but the odds of such a discovery leading to an invention that is going to have a huge or immediate impact on humanity is slim.

There is also the opportunity to learn and perform research in the enviroment.  In a further future setting you could imagine a deep-sea lab that is intentionally constructed to allow experiments at extremely high pressure perhaps, though it seems like it would be much easier to artificially create a high pressure enviroment for such experiments then to build a lab or research center underwater.

There will continue to be discoveries as we search the ocean, and I suspect humans collective knowledge will increase due to them.  But any benefit to humanity would be decades after the original discovery, as it would take time to figure out a useful way to utilize any of the discoveries we made.

In short, nothing very exciting happened, and nothing all that exciting is likely to come out of future dives for some time.

Comment: Thank you so much! Most complete and favourite awnser so far, exactly what I wanted! You talked about the species but what about lost lands? Civilizations? Is there any chance we could find one? And if so, how would it change all of the Earth Evolution Theory? The history as we know it? And how would it affect science?

Comment: @Jataki fankly no.  were talking massively high pressure with little resources, since sunlight doesn't reach the bottom and that's the source of most life.  Creatures live there, evolution always finds ways, but your not going to have a high concentration of any creature type, much less an actual civilization of any kind.  No remans of past human civilizations will exist because humans could never have lived there, and pressure would destroy what was there.  I'm afraid in this era discoveries like that anywhere on earth are quite unlikely.

Comment: @Jataki the evolution of the creatures that do live that deep are quite separated from us genetically.  We would have split off from any discovered creatures long before even reptiles creatures existed, and they would have continued adapting away from any common ancestor we shared  to survive the depths.  We could find interesting details for how evolution happens in high pressure, maybe, but it wouldn't effect human evolutionary theory.  Since we have so little in common with them, and we already have studied things closer to our common ancestor then them which would yield more useful data.

Answer (score 4):

**Speculation ended in 1960.**

The [Trieste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathyscaphe_Trieste) [went to the bottom of the Marianas Trench](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariana_Trench#Descents) in 1960. Specifically, [Challenger Deep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenger_Deep), the deepest place in the ocean. James Cameron, the director, also went there in 2012 with lots of press. He's the guy who directed Titanic, now that's *really* deep.

What did he find?

[image]

Water, sand, silt, some rocks... Not much. If some distant future civilization goes there [they may find our nuclear waste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariana_Trench#Possible_nuclear_waste_disposal_site), since it seems like a good place to put it, as far away from us as possible.

**How would it change humanity?**

Clearly *not much*, since most people don't even seem to know it happened.

Comment: Clearly =P (+1)

Comment: I beg to differ on your last statement, human progress quite a lot during these years venturing into the deepest part of ocean just to explore. It is no doubt a tiny project but this tiny project have clear a very significant amount of doubts.

Comment: @user6760 I have to admit I'm having a lot of trouble parsing your comment. I am a strong advocate for exploration, Earthly or otherwise. So while the process is incredibly important, this particular feat had little direct impact on humanity.

Comment: You're not alone I get that quite a lot. I'm not referring to the discovery that shatters imaginations... It is the development of materials durable to withstand enormous pressure and the life support pod specifically designed to allow average adult human to fit and work comfortably also the technology to capture images at low lights I believe all these developments had much more impact on our understanding of the world. Not enough convincing check out moon landing by Neil Armstrong. One small step for man... sorry I forgot the rest anyway let's agree to disagree so drinks on me cheer.

Comment: Very cool, but I was talking about being able to scan/explore all the ocean and, primarily, reaching the Earth's core

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you seek to accomplish already has.

[Deep-Submergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep-submergence_vehicle)

That being said, oceans make up most of the planet, and are ridiculously vast which is why there is still plenty to explore.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Challenger Deep [has been visited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenger_Deep#Descents), but not the [HMRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMRG_Deep), [Galathea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galathea_Depth), or [Tonga deeps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonga_Trench), all of which have similar depths (over 10k meters) and potentially interesting features.

Tonga is fascinating, since it's at a convergent plate boundary - the crust is literally being subducted to raise islands. That means it has probably some of the oldest rocks on earth still in existence that contain fossils of marine life. That itself is worth the trip (though they would have to dig through the spongy layer of diatomaceous life at the bottom, if Challenger Deep is any indication.)

Still, your bathysphere can withstand 6,371 km of water pressure, and we're only using a tiny portion of that (11 km = .117%) pressure capacity. The density of water is just under [1 megagram (1000 kg)/m^3](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=water%20density). The pressure at the bottom of the Mariana trench is only 15,750 psi = 108 MegaPascals (MPa). We can withstand up to 999.97 (kg/m^3 density of water) * 9.8 (m^2/s force of gravity) * 6.371*10^6 (m radius of earth) = ***62.4358 GIGAPASCALS***

A more interesting proposal - if those special bathyspheres can stand that much columnar pressure, we should send them to the gas giants in our solar system to see what "lies beneath," and possibly discover the metallic hydrogen theorized to exist there. Or to Neptune, and discover why it radiates more heat than it receives from the sun...

Comment: None of the crust formed in the oceans is very old.  Crust forms at the spreading centers and is subducted back into the mantle at trenches.  Continents, especially in the centers, hold much older fossils including seafloor deposits as some material gets scraped off and crushed into the leading edge of a moving continent.